# How to show the link is clickable ? Mobile UI Design

Tags: interface-design, mobile

I am prototyping a profile interface for a social network app and I can't figure out how to show that the links in the "Progression" card are clickable.

I put some interrogations points, to point out you can get explanations by clicking on the titles but my testers always miss them.

Do you have any tips ?

[image]

Comment: This is mostly a UX problem, but there are many possible ways to show that an element is clickable in an interface. Whatever you choose, just make sure it's consistent throughout the whole app.

Comment: there are some insights here, nothing specific for mobile but the general idea is still useful https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/how-can-i-ensure-that-users-will-think-a-button-is-clickable/2647#2647

Comment: Honestly,, if they don't "get" the (?) or an (i).. then it's user error, not design error. (?) is *very standard* for "more information" links.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a very simple option but even just underlining the link text is a good way to denote that something is clickable. I would say putting some arrow icons on the right hand side may also work but the text would have to then break over multiple lines with could cause issues.

Very nice design though!